# Can an Azure template contain a virus, a backdoor or malware?

Tags: malware, azure

Sometimes you can find projects on the internet that can propose you to import a template to Azure, like [this one](https://github.com/StratusOn/S3-to-Blob).

You have a button and if you click it allows you to deploy:

[image]

Then you go through the normal procedure and you put those stuff that are going to be created inside a Resource Group.

But you are actually deploying complex stuff like Storage Accounts, ADF, or C# code contained into Logic Apps, or PowerShell code into a workbook that can actually be executed.

Does Azure stops malicious Azure templates?

Does Azure Defender for Cloud scan the templates before deployment?

Comment: Of course templates could contain all that. And it doesn't need to be a "virus" because you are literally configuring code to do what you want. No need to be "sneaky". AV scanners are not going to pick up the configuration of ports and explicit code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does Azure stops malicious Azure templates?

No. Because malicious is not clearly defined. What is *wanted* behaviour for me, may be malicious in your solution.

The S3-Azure copy tool you link may be something I want to use, due to a migration or using both clouds. In your case it may be malicious, because it copies privileged data outside permitted storage locations.

You have - as always - to understand and know what the software you are running are doing, and you have to trust whomever you let configure or supply the software.